# search array of strings by partially match in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I got fields like that:
`names: ["Red:123", "Blue:45", "Green:56"]`
it's mapping is

```
"names": {
    "type": "keyword"
},
```

how could I search like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "names": "red"
    }
  }
}
```

to get all the documents where `red` is in element of `names` array?
Now it works only with

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "names": "red:123"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can add [multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) OR just change the type to `text`, to achieve your required result**

**Index Mapping using `multi fields`**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "names": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": { 
            "type":  "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "names":{
        "type":"text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "names": [
    "Red:123",
    "Blue:45",
    "Green:56"
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "names": "red"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64665127",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "names": [
            "Red:123",
            "Blue:45",
            "Green:56"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Егор Лебедев please go through my answer, and let me know if this is your required search result? The `match` query works fine and gives the required result.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that mapping is `keyword`

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев can you make changes in your mapping?

Comment: I think I am not, I could use `prefix` or `wildcard` instead of `match` but as I understand from docs it is expensive operations, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, @ЕгорЛебедев Searching with leading wildcards is quite expensive and is going to be extremely slow on a large index and will affect your search performance.

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев can you add one extra field in your mapping, if yes then the `match` query will work? Let me know if you can do this so that I could provide a working example for the same

Comment: I need to contact DB admin for that, so what variants do I have? add additional element or change type to text?

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев you can do either of them, can add multi fields https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#multi-fields OR just change the type to `text`

Comment: Please add this to your answer and I will accept it

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев added the multi fields part to my answer :)